# How can I make a magical photocopier?

Tags: magic, ars-magica, ars-magica-5

One of my players wants a way to reproduce books quickly in an Ars Magica (5th edition) setting.

What spells exist (preferably without using vis) to accomplish this goal?

Comment: 1.magically enslave 100 monks 3. Profit

Comment: @mxyzplk - What's phase 2?

Comment: @Cthos You have to ask the underpants gnomes.

Comment: I've tried this in earlier editions and found it was much cheaper in terms of time to teach a mundane scribe some magic theory and have them copy books for you. Just be careful the first time you use them, just in case they botched their Magic Theory roll. *8') This technique also has the benefit than the NPC can have skills and virtues tailored to scribing quickly and well, so you can end up with texts of a *much* higher quality than most Magi could produce on their own.

Comment: The difficulty of reproducing information is probably the most vivid demonstration of the difference between the medieval ages and modern day that _Ars Magica_ provides.  The expense and rarity of ink, parchment, scribes, and skilled bookbinders all nicely highlight the spectacular achievement that is the printing press.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this question is now very old.
However, I think it's useful to point out that there is now a published canonical answer to this exact question.

It's covered in the supplement *[Transforming Mythic Europe](http://www.atlas-games.com/product_tables/AG0306.php)*, on pages 98-108. The section heading is "The Copying of a Book". A number of spells are included, and a complete magic item design for an integrated "photocopier" Greater Enchanted Item based on several linked effects.

Comment: We applaud answering old questions with new answers - and this one's great!

Answer (score 13):

Without Vis means that instead of magically creating the paper/parchment and ink, you need to supply it yourself.

As for the spell, there is a spell in the True Lineages book we can use as basis: Exactly to scale

True Lineages, Page 139:

> **Exactly to Scale**
>
> Rego Aquam, Requisite Mentem, Level 10
>
> Draw a picture of the magus ideas. Requires ink and a drawing surface,
>   since it uses mundane materials to draw.
>
> Intellige + Finesse roll +9
>   for the drawing be legible.   Base 3, +1 Touch, +2 for highly
>   unnatural control

So, for a magical photocopier, we need not the magus ideas as source, but the writing on a page.
I would say, changing the requisite to Intellego would suffice, but if you want to make it a little bit harder you could add Terram as requisite, since most inks where metal based.

**So for Copy a single page we have:**

> Rego Aquam, Requisite Intellego + possibly Terram, Level 10
>
> Base 3, +1 Touch, +2 for highly unnatural control

**You want to copy a 100 page book?**

We need to go for group target + one size increment:

> Copy book:
>
> Rego Aquam, Requisite Intellego + possibly Terram, Level
>   25
>
> Base 3, +1 Touch, + 2 Group, +1 size, +2 for highly unnatural
>   control

Now, since it is easier to make errors if you have more text to copy, I would say, that the finesse roll should be way higher or maybe a concentration roll is for required for each 5/10 or so pages copied.

An alternative solution would be to add to the spell magnitude for lower finesse / concentration. Maybe +2/+3 for exact design (similar to the +3 elaborate design in Conjouring the mystics tower).
With a +3 exact design we would end with a level 40 spell.
How much you add depends on how easy you would make it your player magus to copy it.

And: Errors could be painful.

A corrupted magical book could lead to some unpleasant encounters in the lab!
So a missed finesse, concentration etc. roll could be dangerous.